# Selenium not sending keys to alert

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

It is a site that has a list of pin codes and only one is correct. To check the PIN code there is a <kbd>check</kbd> button. I need to press check button then paste pin to alert and accept in, then depending on
the message I need to do other stuff.

The problem is when I'm trying to use `send_keys()` method program crashes with this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: {Alert text : 
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
```

I've tried adding `time.sleep()`, `execute_script` with `js` code to pass a pin, but still have crash.

If I remove `send_keys()` method program works fine, but since I add it back it isn`t.

Here is my code:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

with webdriver.Chrome() as browser:
    browser.get('https://parsinger.ru/blank/modal/4/index.html')

    codes = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pin')
    btn = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'check')
    res = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'result')

    for code in codes:
        btn.click()
        alert = browser.switch_to.alert
        alert.send_keys(code.text)
        alert.accept()

        if res.text != 'Неверный пин-код':
            print(f'Правильный код: {code.text} ')
            print(f'Секретный код: {res.text}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause of the Issue:** You are first clicking on the alert and when the alert is open, you are trying to access web element on the main page and trying to get the text of it. In this code `alert.send_keys(code.text)`

**Solution:** Get the text of the `<span>` element before clicking on the alert button.
Just change your for loop as below: **Notice am capturing text of  element before clicking on alert button.**

```
for code in codes:
    pin = code.text
    btn.click()
    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
    alert.send_keys(pin)
    alert.accept()
```

**Result:**

```
Правильный код: 1000 
Секретный код: 1261851212132345456274632

Process finished with exit code 0
```